# Insert JSON object into .json file using php

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON file stored in a server. I am using a php script to add another object to this JSON file.

testjson1.json:

```
{
"feed": 
[
{
"id": "1",
"name": "Ram",
"status": "Very good restaurant!! water tastes soo good :)"
}
]
}
```

The php that i use to add an object is as follows:

```
<?php
$data=array("2","new","not so good");
$inp = file_get_contents('testjson1.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
array_push($tempArray, $data);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('testjson1.json', $jsonData);
?>
```

But the php file shows an error which says:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /home/u160481344/public_html/jsonfinder.php on line 5

and the json file collapses into a single line. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add second boolean parameter TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative array.

Just replace this line

```
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
```

With this

```
$tempArray = json_decode($inp,true);
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/json_decode), if you don't want object from `json_decode`

```
   json_decode($tempArray, true);
```

Add second boolean parameter. Try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

PHP function `json_decode()` decodes a JSON string, it takes a JSON encoded string and convert it into PHP variable.

The script written below return a PHP variable in an object data type.

```
$inp = file_get_contents('testjson1.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
```

But PHP function `array_push()` accepts only array as input parameters. There is a second parameter (optional) **boolean** type you can pass into the json_decode() function like **`json_decode($json_string, TRUE)`** which will return decode PHP variable in an associative array.
You have to update your code like this -

```
$inp = file_get_contents('testjson1.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp, TRUE);
```

For more reference see this link PHP function [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).